# Wrong contenttype XQuery xbrl MarkLogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, xbrl

My uploader handles things very well when uploading content to my MarkLogic database

```
declare function local:uploadFile()
{
for $file at $pos in xdmp:get-request-field("upload")
    let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")[$pos]
    let $contenttype := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")[$pos]
    let $extension := fn:replace($filename, '.*\.', '')[$pos]
    let $insert := switch ($contenttype)
        case "text/xml"
        case "text/xhtml"
        case "text/csv"
        case "text/plain"
        case "application/json"
            return xdmp:document-insert($filename,xdmp:unquote($file))
        case "application/octet-stream"
            return switch ($extension)
            case "gpx"
                return xdmp:document-insert($filename,xdmp:unquote(xdmp:quote(binary{xs:hexBinary($file)})))
            default
                return xdmp:document-insert($filename,$file)
        default
            return xdmp:document-insert($filename,$file)
    return fn:concat("file '",$filename,"' uploaded, contenttype: ",$contenttype," extension: ",$extension)
};
```

Problem is that this document is seen as XML/XBRL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/ef/xbrl/uk/fr/gaap/ae/2009-06-21/stylesheet/CH-AE-dormant-stylesheet.xsl"?>
<xbrl
    xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ae="http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/ef/xbrl/uk/fr/gaap/ae/2009-06-21"
    xmlns:gc="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/fr/gcd/2004-12-01"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
    xmlns:pt="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/fr/gaap/pt/2004-12-01"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <link:schemaRef xlink:arcrole="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink/properties/linkbase" 
xlink:href="http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/ef/xbrl/uk/fr/gaap/ae/2009-06-21/uk-gaap-ae-2009-06-21.xsd" 
xlink:type="simple"/>
    <ae:CompanyDormant contextRef="y2017">true</ae:CompanyDormant>
    <gc:EntityNames>
        <gc:EntityCurrentLegalName contextRef="y2017">HUNTS GROUP PLC</gc:EntityCurrentLegalName>
    </gc:EntityNames>
    <ae:CompanyIdentifyingNumbers>
        <ae:CompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber contextRef="y2017">03975172</ae:CompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber>
    </ae:CompanyIdentifyingNumbers>
    <gc:StatementDatesPeriodsCovered>
        <gc:BalanceSheetDate contextRef="e2017">2017-04-30</gc:BalanceSheetDate>
    </gc:StatementDatesPeriodsCovered>
    <pt:ShareholderFunds precision="6" contextRef="e2017" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:ShareholderFunds>
    <pt:ShareholderFunds precision="6" contextRef="e2016" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:ShareholderFunds>
    <pt:NetAssetsLiabilitiesIncludingPensionAssetLiability precision="5" contextRef="e2017" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:NetAssetsLiabilitiesIncludingPensionAssetLiability>
    <pt:NetAssetsLiabilitiesIncludingPensionAssetLiability precision="5" contextRef="e2016" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:NetAssetsLiabilitiesIncludingPensionAssetLiability>
    <pt:CashBankInHand precision="5" contextRef="e2017" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:CashBankInHand>
    <pt:CashBankInHand precision="5" contextRef="e2016" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:CashBankInHand>
    <pt:EquityAuthorisedDetails>
        <pt:TypeOrdinaryShare contextRef="y2017">Ordinary</pt:TypeOrdinaryShare>
        <pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAuthorised precision="INF" contextRef="e2017" unitRef="shares">50000</pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAuthorised>
        <pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare precision="INF" contextRef="y2017" unitRef="GBP">1</pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare>
    </pt:EquityAuthorisedDetails>
    <pt:DetailsOrdinarySharesAllotted>
        <pt:TypeOrdinaryShare contextRef="y2017">Ordinary</pt:TypeOrdinaryShare>
        <pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare precision="INF" contextRef="y2017" unitRef="GBP">1</pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare>
        <pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted precision="5" contextRef="e2017" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted>
        <pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted precision="5" contextRef="e2016" unitRef="GBP">12500</pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted>
        <pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAllotted precision="INF" contextRef="e2017" unitRef="shares">12500</pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAllotted>
    </pt:DetailsOrdinarySharesAllotted>
    <pt:DateApproval contextRef="e2017">2017-10-13</pt:DateApproval>
    <pt:ApprovalDetails>
        <pt:NameApprovingDirector contextRef="y2017">Mr. David Charles Hunt</pt:NameApprovingDirector>
    </pt:ApprovalDetails>
    <ae:CompanyEntitledToExemptionUnderSection480CompaniesAct2006 contextRef="y2017">true</ae:CompanyEntitledToExemptionUnderSection480CompaniesAct2006>
    <ae:MembersHaveNotRequiredCompanyToObtainAnAudit contextRef="y2017">true</ae:MembersHaveNotRequiredCompanyToObtainAnAudit>
    <ae:DirectorsAcknowledgeTheirResponsibilitiesUnderCompaniesAct contextRef="y2017">true</ae:DirectorsAcknowledgeTheirResponsibilitiesUnderCompaniesAct>
    <ae:AccountsAreInAccordanceWithSpecialProvisionsCompaniesActRelatingToSmallCompanies contextRef="y2017">true</ae:AccountsAreInAccordanceWithSpecialProvisionsCompaniesActRelatingToSmallCompanies>
    <unit id="shares">
        <measure>xbrli:shares</measure>
    </unit>
    <unit id="GBP">
        <measure>iso4217:GBP</measure>
    </unit>
    <unit id="pure">
        <measure>xbrli:pure</measure>
    </unit>
    <context id="y2017">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="/results">HUNTS GROUP PLC</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <startDate>2016-05-01</startDate>
            <endDate>2017-04-30</endDate>
        </period>
    </context>
    <context id="y2016">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="/results">HUNTS GROUP PLC</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <startDate>2015-05-01</startDate>
            <endDate>2016-04-30</endDate>
        </period>
    </context>
    <context id="s2016">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="/results">HUNTS GROUP PLC</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <instant>2015-04-30</instant>
        </period>
    </context>
    <context id="e2016">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="/results">HUNTS GROUP PLC</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <instant>2016-04-30</instant>
        </period>
    </context>
    <context id="s2017">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="/results">HUNTS GROUP PLC</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <instant>2016-04-30</instant>
        </period>
    </context>
    <context id="e2017">
        <entity>
            <identifier scheme="/results">HUNTS GROUP PLC</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
            <instant>2017-04-30</instant>
        </period>
    </context>
    <ae:CompaniesHouseDocumentAuthentication contextRef="y2017"></ae:CompaniesHouseDocumentAuthentication>
    <ae:DateAccountsReceived contextRef="e2017">2017-10-16</ae:DateAccountsReceived>
</xbrl>
```

Due to limits on this site I am unable to post the whole document that is giving me problems. So here is only the header for the document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xml:lang="nl" xmlns:kvk-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/kvk/20171213/dictionary/kvk-data" xmlns:venj-bw2-dm="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/venj/20171213/dictionary/venj-bw2-domains" xmlns:venj-bw2-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/venj/20171213/dictionary/venj-bw2-data" xmlns:rj-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/rj/20171213/dictionary/rj-data" xmlns:rj-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/rj/20171213/dictionary/rj-tuples"   xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:nl-cd="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/sbr/20170515/dictionary/nl-common-data" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:venj-bw2-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/venj/20171213/dictionary/venj-bw2-axes">
    <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/kvk/20171213/entrypoints/kvk-rpt-jaarverantwoording-2017-nlgaap-middelgroot-publicatiestukken.xsd"/>
    <xbrli:context id="FY17d">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.kvk.nl/kvk-id">30267975</xbrli:identifier>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2017-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2017-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
    </xbrli:context>
```

This document is seen by my uploader al the last case an `"application/octet-stream"` and i do not understand why. Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an extra case, `case "xbrl"`, in the upload.xqy file fixes this problem:

```
declare function local:uploadFile()
{
for $file at $pos in xdmp:get-request-field("upload")
    let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")[$pos]
    let $contenttype := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")[$pos]
    let $extension := fn:replace($filename, '.*\.', '')[$pos]
    let $insert := switch ($contenttype)
        case "text/xml"
        case "text/xhtml"
        case "text/csv"
        case "text/plain"
        case "application/json"
            return xdmp:document-insert($filename,xdmp:unquote($file))
        case "application/octet-stream"
            return switch ($extension)
            case "gpx"
            case "xbrl"
                return xdmp:document-insert($filename,xdmp:unquote(xdmp:quote(binary{xs:hexBinary($file)})))
            default
                return xdmp:document-insert($filename,$file)
        default
            return xdmp:document-insert($filename,$file)
    return fn:concat("file '",$filename,"' uploaded, contenttype: ",$contenttype," extension: ",$extension)
};
```

Comment: It might also help to declare the xbrl mimetype and extension inside MarkLogic using the Admin UI in the so-called Mimetypes section. Perhaps something to explore in a later stage.